# unexpected loop cycles with jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to print a table in bash to stdout from json with `jq`:

```
[
    {
      "key": "name",
      "doc_count": 1000,
      "values_over_time": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key_as_string": "2019-05-01 11:00:00.000",
            "key": 1556708400000,
            "doc_count": 50
          },
          {
            "key_as_string": "2019-05-02 12:00:00.000",
            "key": 1556798400000,
            "doc_count": 40
          },
          {
            "key_as_string": "2019-05-02 13:00:00.000",
            "key": 1556802000000,
            "doc_count": 30
          }
        ]
      }
    }
]
```

With `jq -r '(.[].key + " " + .[].values_over_time[][].key_as_string) + " " + (.[].values_over_time[][].doc_count|tostring)'` I get these results:

```
"name 2019-05-01 11:00:00.000 50"
"name 2019-05-02 12:00:00.000 50"
"name 2019-05-02 13:00:00.000 50"
"name 2019-05-01 11:00:00.000 40"
"name 2019-05-02 12:00:00.000 40"
"name 2019-05-02 13:00:00.000 40"
"name 2019-05-01 11:00:00.000 30"
"name 2019-05-02 12:00:00.000 30"
"name 2019-05-02 13:00:00.000 30"
```

There is something strange with additional loop level as I expect to see only 3 lines:

```
"name 2019-05-01 11:00:00.000 50"
"name 2019-05-02 12:00:00.000 40"
"name 2019-05-02 13:00:00.000 30"
```

Read `jq` docs but wasn't able to understand the right way to iterate in a proper in a neat way. Do you have any clues?

[JQplay code sample](https://jqplay.org/s/d9Lo9Wu--y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expanding `values_over_time` twice, thus 3 * 3 = 9 outputs are generated. Do something like this instead:

```
.[] | .key + " " + (.values_over_time.buckets[] | "\(.key_as_string) \(.doc_count)")
```

Compare these two commands to see the difference clearly:

```
$ jq -nc '[1,2,3] | [.[]*.[]]'
[1,2,3,2,4,6,3,6,9]
```

```
$ jq -nc '[1,2,3] | [.[]|.*.]'
[1,4,9]
```

Comment: thanks a lot - you are my brain's savior! Will try to experiment with `jq` syntax and iterations more, thanks for these examples. And now I also know about `-nc` as a little playground that is always at hand.

Answer (score 1):

The technical reason is that you're combining expressions that generate multiple results. And the way jq operates, it will generate results for every combination of those subexpressions.

Looking at your filter and your input, here's how many results are generated by each subexpression:

```
(.[].key + " " + .[].values_over_time[][].key_as_string) + " " + (.[].values_over_time[][].doc_count|tostring)
(1         1     3)                                        1     (3                                 | 1)
(1 * 1 * 3 = 3)                                            1     (3 * 1 = 3)
 3 * 1 * 3 = 9
```

This is why you must *always* take care in using expressions that generate multiple results (e.g., `[]`).

As Oguz points out, you need to write it such that the input is expanded only once in the expression. Usually right at the beginning of the filter is best.

This could be done in many ways, I would write it like so:

```
.[] | "\(.key) \(.values_over_time.buckets[] | "\(.key_as_string) \(.doc_count)")"
1   |   (1)     (3                           |   (1)               (1))
1   |   (1)     (3                           | 1 * 1 = 1)
1   |   (1)     (3 * 1 = 3)
1   | (1 * 3 = 3)
1 * 3 = 3
```